# difference in code between .doc and .docx documents with inserting image in footer

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to insert image in Word at specific location in footer. I'm using this code for **".doc"** documents:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CATMain()
Dim strPathImg As String
strPathImg = "C:\Test\Img.png"
Dim wrdApp
Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wrdApp.Visible = True
Dim myWrdDoc
Set myWrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open("C:\Test\Document.doc") 'chage path for .docx to: "C:\Test\Document.docx"
Dim wrdFootShape
Set wrdFootShape = myWrdDoc.Sections.Last.Footers(1).Shapes
Dim objPic As Object
Set objPic = wrdFootShape.AddPicture(FileName:=strPathImg, 
LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True, Left:=120, Top:=50)
End Sub
```

and this works great except on **".docx"** documents. This line of code don't insert image, and don't show any error.

what should be approach for inserting image on specific location in footer in ".docx" type of documents?

Thanks in advance, appreciate every answer

Comment: Which version of Word is this running in? My gut feeling is that the object is being inserted off-page (too high or too far to the left, for example). This happened in Word 2013, as I recall... If you then put in `objPic.ConvertToInlineShape` does the graphic appear? (I know, it's not where or what is wanted, but as a test...)

Comment: @ Cindy Meister I'm using Word 2010. Nothing changes when I convert objPic to InLineShape. If set objPic.Left = 120 and objPic.Top = 50 picture is still not there where is in .doc document :(

Comment: @ Cindy Meister you were right. Pic was off the screen. doc and docx take different starting point for calculation of ".Top" position of image. For ".doc" 0 is top position of footer, and for ".docx" 0 is top of paper

Comment: OK, since this could happen to others I'm going to write it up as an answer. Note: I didn't see your comments because you put spaces in the "ping". Correct would be the way the "tip" appears at the top left of the comment box when you type @ + characters. For me: @cindymeister

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some versions of Word tend to push a graphics object off the page (too high, too low, too far to the left or to the right). A new graphics engine was introduced with the new file formats and is likely (at least partially) responsible for this difference between doc and docx.

For the example in the question, **doc** files interpret the the positional properties relative to the `StoryRange` where the `Shape` is being inserted. For **docx** files, this will most likely be relative to the document page, not the specific `Story`. (The language reference for `AddPicture` mentions relative to *the drawing canvas*.)

The code in the question positions the graphic 50 points down from the top, which is pushing it below the page on a ***doc*** file. In a ***docx*** file, the graphic is positioned near the top of the document.

The following code sample, based on the code in the question, shows how this can be allowed for by testing the `SaveFormat` of the document. Other Save Formats are possible, this only deals with the two file formats under discussion.

```
'Insert Shape into Footer
'behaves differently for doc/docx
Sub CATMain()
    Dim strPathImg As String
    strPathImg = "C:\Test\avatar.jpg"
    Dim wrdApp
    Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wrdApp.Visible = True
    Dim myWrdDoc
    Set myWrdDoc = 'wrdApp.Documents.Open("C:\Test\Document.doc") 'change path for .docx to: "C:\Test\Document.docx"

    Dim wrdFootShape
    Set wrdFootShape = myWrdDoc.Sections.Last.Footers(1).Shapes
    Dim objPic As Object
    Dim posPic As Double
    'Convert position in centimeters to points for the AddPicture method
    posPic = CentimetersToPoints(2)

    If myWrdDoc.SaveFormat = 0 Then
        'correction for doc file
        posPic = posPic - myWrdDoc.PageSetup.PageHeight + myWrdDoc.PageSetup.TopMargin
    ElseIf myWrdDoc.SaveFormat = 12 Then
        'docx file
        posPic = posPic
    End If
    Set objPic = wrdFootShape.AddPicture(fileName:=strPathImg, _
      LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True, Left:=120, Top:=posPic)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for answer.
In your answer you referenced on page margin (`myWrdDoc.PageSetup.TopMargin`), but for footer you need to take footer margin (`myWrdDoc.PageSetup.FooterDistance`). So I would say that best approach for setting picture position in **.doc** file is to calculate it from the bottom. In my case: `posPic = myWrdDoc.PageSetup.FooterDistance - 62`. That way you have picture on same spot with any margin position.